# Is it possible for a Bookmarklet to communicate with Browser Extensions?

Tags: bookmarklet, browser-extension

I have a bookmarklet and i want to develop chrome/firefox/safari extensions, extensions that should communicate with the bookmarklet;

Is this possible, and if so, does anyone have any docs?